# How do I check if my assignment is using the right variable?

Tags: c#, antlr4, visitor-pattern

i'm using visitor from ANTLR4 to develop an interpreter in c#. 
in my grammar, i have a rule for looping and a rule for assignment as below:

```
for_stmt
: FOR  EACH  ID  IN  collection  DO NEWLINE+
         (block NEWLINE*)?
  END  FOR
;

set_stmt
:SET  ID '.' ID TO  arithExpr
;

block
: for_stmt
| set_stmt
;
```

inside the for loop, we can have set statements like this:

```
for each record in recordCollection do
    set record.name to 10
end for
```

the **record** used inside the set statement must be the same as the **record** used in the loop. how can i check this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your visitor can maintain a stack of variable definitions (scopes):

- The visit method for `for_stmt` pushes the variable declarations onto the stack (and pops it after visiting the child nodes)
- The visit method for `set_stmt` inspects the stack and throws a runtime exception if it cannot find the accessed id on the stack